# Dask dataframe join slow as pandas

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have 2 dataframes, one called animes ~10k rows of data, one called animelists ~30M rows of data, and want to join them. I benchmarked it with pandas, and it is faster only around 7% speedup, which is not much and I wonder if it can be faster if I have 16 cores.

I have pandas Dataframes, where I set indices

```
animes = animes.set_index('anime_id')
animelists = animelists.set_index('anime_id')
```

The data looks like this (I ommited other columns), animes:

```
anime_id | genres
-------- | ------
11013    | Comedy, Supernatural, Romance, Shounen
2104     | Comedy, Parody, Romance, School, Shounen
5262     | Comedy, Magic, School, Shoujo
```

and animelists:

```
anime_id | username | my_score
21       | karthiga | 9
59       | karthiga | 7
74       | karthiga | 7
```

and then I created Dask Dataframes from this

```
animes_dd = dd.from_pandas(animes, npartitions=8)
animelists_dd = dd.from_pandas(animelists, npartitions=8)
```

I want to join effectively individual anime genres with animelists to query scores by genres. I have code to do that here in pandas:

```
genres_arr = animes['genres'].str.replace(' ', '').str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).to_frame(name='genre')
genres_arr = genres_arr[genres_arr['genre'] != '']
resulting_df = animelists.merge(genres_arr, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
# this takes 1min 37s
```

and same code in dask:

```
genres_arr_dd = animes_dd['genres'].map_partitions(lambda x: x.str.replace(' ', '').str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1)).to_frame(name='genre')
genres_arr_dd = genres_arr_dd[genres_arr_dd['genre'] != '']
resulting_dd = animelists_dd.merge(genres_arr_dd, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True).compute()
# this takes 1min 30s
```

(the resulting dataframe has ~140M rows)

Is there any way to speed it up more? I followed the [official performance guide](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html), I perform joins on indexed columns, and have 8 partitions on each Dask Dataframe, so it should be prepared for effective multiprocessing join.

What is wrong here and how should I speed it up more?

When I ran the code in jupyter notebook, I was watching per-core CPU utilization, and it was very low, and some time, only one core was active, and ran at 100%. It seems that it does not parallelize well.

Comment: You got a speedup, hurray!

Comment: Yes, but very negligible, I supposed the multithreading would show bigger speedup compared to singlethread version on the task which is supposed to be parallelized well. 
If this is the max capability of Dask, then the Dask is big disappointment.

Comment: Parallelism isn't magic, there are a large number of tradeoffs

Comment: I know that parallelism isn't magic. Using only pandas and joblib with 8 threads, I managed to optimize the code so I get the same dataset in 1 min 4s, which is more significant speedup. Something like I expected from Dask, apparently it's more efficient to do such tasks by directly using multithreading .

Comment: No, multiple processes, that's the important point here

Comment: I tried dask with both multiple processes and multiple threads in one process, the time was almost the same. Neither one was faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been repeated elsewhere, so I will keep it very brief.

- from_pandas->compute means that you are roundtripping all the data; you want to load in the workers (e.g., dd.read_csv) and aggregate in the workers, not move whole datasets to and from
- the choice of scheduler is very important. If your system monitor says you are using one CPU, you are probably limited by the GIL and should try the distributed scheduler, with appropriate process/thread mix. It will also give you more diagnostics on its dashboard about what is going on
- Pandas is fast, and when the data is small, the additional overhead of dask, although also small, may outweigh any parallelism you get.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know that from_pandas->compute is problem, I never saw in documentation that I should not use it. I thout it splits the data to 8 workers.
Thanks, I will try to load data using dask and tinker with scheduler a bit.
I am aware that Pandas is fast on small data, and I actually observed that operations on ~10-50k rows were faster in pandas than in dask. 
I thought 30M to 140M rows should be big enough to see the difference.

Comment: So I tried all possibilities, Pandas + Joblib did the job fastest.

Comment: dask distributed with processes is essentially the same. The multiprocessing scheduler is even more similar to joblib, but not used often any more, as the distributed one gives you all the nice diagnostic.